# Recursive CTE to get employees by their manager

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, recursion, common-table-expression

Write a recursive CTE that will get employees by their manager. Include the following columns:

- Employee LastName
- Employee FirstName
- Department ID
- FileFolder
- Manager LastName
- Manager FirstName

The column called `FileFolder` is used to store the performance review for each employee. Note since managers will also have access to all the people that report to them either directly or indirectly, each manager’s folder will eventually be setup to contain not just their own performance review files, but also all the subfolders for each of the employees that report directly to them. To help facilitate that, also include a column called “File Path” that will determine and show the file path name for each employee using Windows style of \ between subfolders, ie. in the format `ManagerFileFolder\EmployeeFileFolder\` etc.

To illustrate how this would work, if for example I reported directly to Dev Sainani and Dev reports to Peter Devlin, then my File Path would be `PeterDevlin\DevSainani\OsamAl`

I am not sure how I am to include columns that are not in the database table I am provided without altering the table and how to incorporate the "File Path" requirements mentioned above.

This is the script for the `Employees` table (the only table I'm provided):

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Employees 
(
    EmployeeID        INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    DepartmentID      INT 
        CONSTRAINT FK_Employee_Department 
            FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dbo.Departments (DepartmentID),
    ManagerEmployeeID INT 
        CONSTRAINT FK_Employee_Manager 
            FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dbo.Employees (EmployeeID),
    FirstName         NVARCHAR(60),
    LastName          NVARCHAR(60),
    Salary            MONEY 
        CONSTRAINT CK_EmployeeSalary CHECK (Salary >= 0),
    CommissionBonus   MONEY 
        CONSTRAINT CK_EmployeeCommission CHECK (CommissionBonus >= 0),
    FileFolder        NVARCHAR(256) 
        CONSTRAINT DF_FileFolder DEFAULT 'ToBeCreated'
);
```

This is what I have done, I know its not correct because I'm not getting any data shown in the table when I write a `SELECT` statement for this CTE:

```
WITH GetEmployeeByManager AS 
(
    SELECT 
        FirstName, LastName, DepartmentID, FileFolder
    FROM 
        dbo.Employees
    WHERE 
        ManagerEmployeeID IS NULL

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
        e.LastName, e.FirstName, e.DepartmentID, e.FileFolder
    FROM 
        Employees e
    JOIN 
        GetEmployeeByManager ge ON e.ManagerEmployeeID = ge.ManagerEmployeeID
)
SELECT *
FROM GetEmployeeByManager ge
JOIN dbo.Employees e ON ge.ManagerEmployeeID = e.ManagerEmployeeID;
```

Comment: `ON e.ManagerEmployeeID = ge.ManagerEmployeeID` is definitely incorrect. One of those should be `EmployeeID`

Comment: Thank you for pointing that error out! Did not see that.

Comment: The first column for anchor member and recursive member of the recursive cte is incorrect. You have it as `FirstName` and `LastName`

Comment: Also you don't need to join to `Employees` table again in the final query

Comment: Hi Squirrel,
Thank you for your response. I was just going off of what notes I had from class. But I see that now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This script gets you the desired output you describe. In the `CREATE` table statement, I removed the foreign key constraints for simplicity as I was using SQL Fiddle to construct this query.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/ce139/6)

**MS SQL Server 2017 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Employees 
(
    EmployeeID        INT not null PRIMARY KEY,
    DepartmentID      INT not null,
    ManagerEmployeeID INT null,
    FirstName         NVARCHAR(60),
    LastName          NVARCHAR(60),
    Salary            MONEY 
        CONSTRAINT CK_EmployeeSalary CHECK (Salary >= 0),
    CommissionBonus   MONEY 
        CONSTRAINT CK_EmployeeCommission CHECK (CommissionBonus >= 0),
    FileFolder        NVARCHAR(256) 
        CONSTRAINT DF_FileFolder DEFAULT 'ToBeCreated'
);

INSERT INTO Employees (EmployeeID, DepartmentID, ManagerEmployeeID, FirstName, LastName, Salary, CommissionBonus, FileFolder)
VALUES (1, 101, null, 'Ted', 'Smith', 12000.00, 120.00, 'TedSmith')
  , (2, 101, 1, 'John','Doe', 10000.00, 100.00, 'JohnDoe')
  , (3, 101, 2, 'Dev', 'Patel', 8000.00, 80.00, 'DevPatel')
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
WITH GetEmployeeByManager AS 
(
    SELECT 
        e.EmployeeID
        , e.FirstName
        , e.LastName
        , e.DepartmentID
        , e.ManagerEmployeeID
        , em.FirstName as ManagerFirstName
        , em.LastName as ManagerLastName
        , e.FileFolder
        , e.FileFolder as FilePath
        , 0 as hierarchy_level
    FROM Employees as e
        LEFT OUTER JOIN Employees as em
            ON em.EmployeeID = e.ManagerEmployeeID
    WHERE e.ManagerEmployeeID is null --First query gets only managers

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
        e.EmployeeID
        , e.FirstName
        , e.LastName
        , e.DepartmentID
        , e.ManagerEmployeeID
        , em.FirstName as ManagerFirstName
        , em.LastName as ManagerLastName
        , e.FileFolder
        , CAST(em.FilePath + '/' + e.FileFolder as nvarchar(256)) as FileFolder
        , em.hierarchy_level + 1 as hierarchy_level
    FROM Employees e
        INNER JOIN GetEmployeeByManager as em
            ON em.EmployeeID = e.ManagerEmployeeID
    WHERE em.hierarchy_level < 50
)
SELECT *
FROM GetEmployeeByManager ge
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/ce139/6/0)**:

```
| EmployeeID | FirstName | LastName | DepartmentID | ManagerEmployeeID | ManagerFirstName | ManagerLastName | FileFolder |                  FilePath | hierarchy_level |
|------------|-----------|----------|--------------|-------------------|------------------|-----------------|------------|---------------------------|-----------------|
|          1 |       Ted |    Smith |          101 |            (null) |           (null) |          (null) |   TedSmith |                  TedSmith |               0 |
|          2 |      John |      Doe |          101 |                 1 |              Ted |           Smith |    JohnDoe |          TedSmith/JohnDoe |               1 |
|          3 |       Dev |    Patel |          101 |                 2 |             John |             Doe |   DevPatel | TedSmith/JohnDoe/DevPatel |               2 |
```

Comment: Thank you for time! Seeing your script now makes the problem make a lot more sense. I am just having difficulty seeing how I am to include the ManagersFirstName and ManagersLastName as columns.

Ill get there!

Comment: @Dylan you have to decide where and how you want to display the manager information. If you want a list of managers going all the way from manager to lowest employee, then you have to make `ManagerFirstName` and `ManagerLastName` columns in the CTE. If you only want to display the employee's immediate supervisor, then you can do a `LEFT OUTER JOIN Employee as e ON e.EmployeeID = ge.ManagerEmployeeID` in the main `SELECT` at the very bottom of the query. Also, for just including immediate supervisor, there is a way to carry it through the CTE but I think it's cumbersome for readability.

Comment: @Dylan, I missed that Manager FirsName and Manager LastName were part of your question. I updated the answer to include those columns as part of the CTE. All you have to do is update the main `SELECT` to include only the columns you want from the CTE.

Comment: Jaroz Thats what i thought i needed to do for the ManagerFirstName and ManagerLastName. But I didnt realize i had to self join the employees table. This helps a lot! Thank you so much!!